# JavaFX: Center a TilePane within a container but not it's children

Tags: javafx

I am attempting to align a TilePane to the top center within the screen in JavaFX. Setting the alignment to `TOP_CENTER` works, but this also seems to affect the children of the child pane.

This is the code I'm testing with - minus the actual TilePane centering as that is what this question is about, and because I haven't found any approach that doesn't have it's own major caveats.

```java
public class TestTilePaneCenter extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var imageUrls = List.of(
                "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.167xw,0&resize=640:*",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529778873920-4da4926a72c2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8Y3V0ZSUyMGNhdHxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80",
                "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/cute-photos-of-cats-curled-up-sleeping-1593184773.jpg"
        );

        var tilePane = new TilePane();
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (var url : imageUrls) {
                var imageView = new ImageView(new Image(url, 100, 100, true, true));
                tilePane.getChildren().add(imageView);
            }
        }

        // TODO: Center the tile pane properly.

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Tile Pane Centering");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tilePane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Notice how the bottom row is centered inwards, which is not intended behaviour.
[image]

Ideally, I would want the children to still stick to the top left, but just ensure that the TilePane itself is kept within the center of the screen.

Essentially like this, but obviously instead of the full TilePane going towards the top left, it should be centered towards the top center.
[image]

I initially thought that I might be able to get away with creating a wrapper container around the tile pane, but that didn't seem to work when all the tiles on the pane were not showing - I imagine likely since the TilePane itself dynamically resizes.

Comment: When you tried the wrapper container approach, did you also set the tile pane's max width/height to `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`? If not, what happens if you do?

Comment: That doesn't seem to change the behavior unfortunately. @Slaw

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfkWY.png

Comment: You set the _wrapper container's_ max width/height. What about when you set the _tile pane's_?

Comment: *”I initially thought that I might be able to get away with creating a wrapper container around the tile pane, but that didn't seem to work when all the tiles on the pane were not showing”* -> what do you mean by this exactly? (put code in the question) What does “doesn’t seem to work” mean?  This *is* the solution.  Place the tile pane in a centering pane, e.g. a VBox with alignment on the VBox set to TOP_CENTER, that centers the tile pane at the top.. Set alignment on the TilePane to TOP_LEFT or some other left aligned value, that aligns the rows in the tile pane left.

Comment: @jewelsea I agree a parent layout that centers the tile pane is the solution. But I do think some kind of limit on the tile pane's width must be enforced (e.g., setting the tile pane's `maxWidth`, setting a vbox's `fillWidth` to false, etc.). Otherwise, when the tiles don't evenly fill the columns of a row, the tile pane will _look_ left aligned rather than centered.

Comment: The the following based on @Slaw and @jewelsea comments. `StackPane root = new StackPane(tilePane);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tilePane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 50, 0, 50));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));`

Comment: @SedJ601 That solution doesn't entirely work - if the number of horizontal tiles does not change the positioning does not change, which is not ideal behaviour.

Comment: @jewelsea Yes, I tried that approach - which is effectively SedJ601's answer - but this has the issue where if the number of horizontal tiles does not change the positioning does not change giving the feel of it being off center.

Comment: I would suggest you look into `ControlsFX` `GridView` to see if it can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses a custom layout based on a TilePane.  It removes the TilePane logic which aligns the last column or row differently from other rows when the last column or row has fewer items than the pref rows or columns set for the tile pane.

The main difficulty here is that the layout of the last row or column is not configurable separately from the overall alignment set on the tile pane.  So the only way to set the alignment of the tile pane to center but still have to last row in the tile pane aligned flush left with the other rows in the tile pane is to override and modify the child layout logic of the tile pane.

Although layoutChildren from the TilePane can be overridden pretty easily, modifying it is a bit tricky because it relies on some methods and functions that are private or package-private, so some of that logic has to be copied into the custom class so that the overridden functions can work.

Run the example and resize the window to make it larger and smaller and see the behavior under resizing.  Re-run it with various settings for the sections in the layout for the application that are commented, to help understand their effect (some of which are pretty subtle and best understood via experimentation).

You might want to try different settings for prefWidth or prefCols of the tile pane (in combination with disabling the VBox container `fillWidth` setting).  Hopefully, you will get the layout you seek with the appropriate combination.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class TestTilePaneCenter extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var imageUrls = List.of(
                "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.167xw,0&resize=640:*",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529778873920-4da4926a72c2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8Y3V0ZSUyMGNhdHxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80",
                "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/cute-photos-of-cats-curled-up-sleeping-1593184773.jpg"
        );

        var tilePane = new UnalignedLastRowOrColumnTilePane();

        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (var url : imageUrls) {
                var imageView = new ImageView(new Image(url, 100, 100, true, true));
                tilePane.getChildren().add(imageView);
            }
        }

        // TODO: Center the tile pane properly.
        VBox layout = new VBox(tilePane);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);     // the tile pane will be centered at the top of the VBox.
        tilePane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);   // all rows in the tile pane will be centered in its available area
        tilePane.setTileAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT); // default is CENTER, keep that if you don't want to change it.
        //layout.setFillWidth(false);              // uncomment if you want the tile pane to be sized to its pref number of columns.
        tilePane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Tile Pane Centering");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 650, 580));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

---

```
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;

import java.util.List;

import static javafx.geometry.Orientation.HORIZONTAL;

public class UnalignedLastRowOrColumnTilePane extends TilePane {
    private int actualRows = 0;
    private int actualColumns = 0;

    private Pos getAlignmentInternal() {
        Pos localPos = getAlignment();
        return localPos == null ? Pos.TOP_LEFT : localPos;
    }

    private Pos getTileAlignmentInternal() {
        Pos localPos = getTileAlignment();
        return localPos == null ? Pos.CENTER : localPos;
    }

    private int computeOther(int numNodes, int numCells) {
        double other = (double)numNodes/(double)Math.max(1, numCells);
        return (int)Math.ceil(other);
    }

    private int computeColumns(double width, double tilewidth) {
        double snappedHgap = snapSpaceX(getHgap());
        return Math.max(1,(int)((width + snappedHgap) / (tilewidth + snappedHgap)));
    }

    private int computeRows(double height, double tileheight) {
        double snappedVgap = snapSpaceY(getVgap());
        return Math.max(1, (int)((height + snappedVgap) / (tileheight + snappedVgap)));
    }

    private double computeContentWidth(int columns, double tilewidth) {
        if (columns == 0) return 0;
        return columns * tilewidth + (columns - 1) * snapSpaceX(getHgap());
    }

    private double computeContentHeight(int rows, double tileheight) {
        if (rows == 0) return 0;
        return rows * tileheight + (rows - 1) * snapSpaceY(getVgap());
    }

    static double computeXOffset(double width, double contentWidth, HPos hpos) {
        switch(hpos) {
            case LEFT:
                return 0;
            case CENTER:
                return (width - contentWidth) / 2;
            case RIGHT:
                return width - contentWidth;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError("Unhandled hPos");
        }
    }

    static double computeYOffset(double height, double contentHeight, VPos vpos) {
        switch(vpos) {
            case BASELINE:
            case TOP:
                return 0;
            case CENTER:
                return (height - contentHeight) / 2;
            case BOTTOM:
                return height - contentHeight;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError("Unhandled vPos");
        }
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        List<Node> managed = getManagedChildren();
        HPos hpos = getAlignmentInternal().getHpos();
        VPos vpos = getAlignmentInternal().getVpos();
        double width = getWidth();
        double height = getHeight();
        double top = snapSpaceY(getInsets().getTop());
        double left = snapSpaceX(getInsets().getLeft());
        double bottom = snapSpaceY(getInsets().getBottom());
        double right = snapSpaceX(getInsets().getRight());
        double vgap = snapSpaceY(getVgap());
        double hgap = snapSpaceX(getHgap());
        double insideWidth = width - left - right;
        double insideHeight = height - top - bottom;

        double tileWidth = getTileWidth() > insideWidth ? insideWidth : getTileWidth();
        double tileHeight = getTileHeight() > insideHeight ? insideHeight : getTileHeight();

        int lastRowRemainder = 0;
        int lastColumnRemainder = 0;
        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            actualColumns = computeColumns(insideWidth, tileWidth);
            actualRows = computeOther(managed.size(), actualColumns);
            // remainder will be 0 if last row is filled  <-- logic removed to allow unaligned last row
//                    lastRowRemainder = hpos != HPos.LEFT?
//                            actualColumns - (actualColumns*actualRows - managed.size()) : 0;
            lastRowRemainder = 0;
        } else {
            // vertical
            actualRows = computeRows(insideHeight, tileHeight);
            actualColumns = computeOther(managed.size(), actualRows);
            // remainder will be 0 if last column is filled  <-- logic removed to allow unaligned last column
//                    lastColumnRemainder = vpos != VPos.TOP?
//                            actualRows - (actualColumns*actualRows - managed.size()) : 0;
            lastColumnRemainder = 0;
        }
        double rowX = left + computeXOffset(insideWidth,
                computeContentWidth(actualColumns, tileWidth),
                hpos);
        double columnY = top + computeYOffset(insideHeight,
                computeContentHeight(actualRows, tileHeight),
                vpos);

        double lastRowX = lastRowRemainder > 0?
                left + computeXOffset(insideWidth,
                        computeContentWidth(lastRowRemainder, tileWidth),
                        hpos) :  rowX;
        double lastColumnY = lastColumnRemainder > 0?
                top + computeYOffset(insideHeight,
                        computeContentHeight(lastColumnRemainder, tileHeight),
                        vpos) : columnY;
        double baselineOffset = -1;

        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0, size = managed.size(); i < size; i++) {
            Node child = managed.get(i);
            double xoffset = r == (actualRows - 1)? lastRowX : rowX;
            double yoffset = c == (actualColumns - 1)? lastColumnY : columnY;

            double tileX = xoffset + (c * (tileWidth + hgap));
            double tileY = yoffset + (r * (tileHeight + vgap));

            Pos childAlignment = getAlignment(child);

            layoutInArea(child, tileX, tileY, tileWidth, tileHeight, baselineOffset,
                    getMargin(child),
                    childAlignment != null? childAlignment.getHpos() : getTileAlignmentInternal().getHpos(),
                    childAlignment != null? childAlignment.getVpos() : getTileAlignmentInternal().getVpos());

            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                if (++c == actualColumns) {
                    c = 0;
                    r++;
                }
            } else {
                // vertical
                if (++r == actualRows) {
                    r = 0;
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect functionally, thank you for your help!